# Call a function when context updates React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I have a functional component that returns another function:

```
function Lobby() {

const user_context = useContext(UserContext)

   return (
        <div>{renderData(user_context.state.data)}</div>
   )
}

export default Lobby;
```

The issue is  when user_context changes, `Lobby()` doesn't update, and so `renderData()` doesn't update. How do I call these functions, when user_context changes?

(EDIT) More details:

```js
    <App />
      <UserContext />
        <Lobby />
          <Introduction />
          <Chapter_1 />
          <Chapter_2 />
          <Chapter_3 />
```

`UserContext` contains a `finishChapter` method, which is called in `Introduction` by a user click. This tells `UserContext` to update the chapter in state, and pass the new chapter to `Lobby`.

**UserContext.js**

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export const UserContext = createContext();

class UserContextProvider extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
        }
    };

    toggleLoading = () => {
        this.setState({loading: !this.state.loading})
        setTimeout(() => {this.setState({loading: !this.state.loading})}, 1000)
    }

    finishChapter = (chapter) => {
        axios.put(`/narrative/finish_chapter/${chapter}`).then((done)=> {
            this.toggleLoading()
            this.getChapter()
        })
    }

    getChapter = () => {
        axios.get('/narrative/get_narrative').then(result => {
            this.setState({
                chapters_complete: result.data[0].chapters_complete,
                number_ch_complete: result.data[0].chapters_complete.length
            })
        })
    }   

    render() {
        return (
            <UserContext.Provider value={{state: this.state, toggleLoading: this.toggleLoading, finishChapter: this.finishChapter }}>
            {this.props.children}
            </UserContext.Provider>
        )
    }

}

export default UserContextProvider;
```

Once the new chapter is added to context, I need `Lobby` to close `Introduction` and open `Chapter_1`.

Right now `Lobby` is receiving the updated context, and I can see it in the Chrome tools (ie: 'Chapter_1'), however it never calls the function.

Comment: Where is `user_context`?

Comment: I dont see `user_context` either and also how do you change the context values?

Comment: I edited the example, hopefully this is more helpful. And the context change is happening from another component, so it isn't visible here.

Comment: `renderLobby` is not a component. It doesn't start with a capital letter. I'm guessing you're just calling `renderLobby()` somewhere instead of using it like a component (e.g. `<RenderLobby />`). If you use it as a component, react with know to re-render it when UserContext changes.

Comment: @Cully - it is a component, I am rendering it from App.js

Comment: Could you update your question to include how you're using this component and how you're updating UserContext?

Comment: how do you update `UserContext`?

Comment: I added the `UserContext.js` file. This is my first attempt at using `Context` so any input is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback, and @Cully for confirming how re-renders and UserContext work.

In the end it was an error in the data structure.

Incorrect:

```
renderData(user_context.state.data)
```

Correct:

```
renderData(user_context.state.data.chapters_complete)
```

Very silly mistake, but the helpful feedback led me to the correct answer. Thank you SO community.